# In Django, how do I construct my queryset to filter by time over slices of time?

Tags: python-3.x, django, datetime, django-queryset, django-filter

I'm using Python 3.9 and Django 3.2.  I have this price model

```
class Price(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    price = models.FloatField(null=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(null=False, default=datetime.now)
```

If I want to get the price per hour over the last 24 hours, I can run a method like this

```
def _get_prices_per_time_slice(self, last_hours=24):
    now = timezone.now()
    end_time = now.replace(second = 0, microsecond = 0)
    start_time = end_time - timedelta(hours=last_hours)
    qset = Price.objects.filter(
        created__range=[start_time, end_time],
        created__minute=end_time.minute
    ).values('price')
    return [r['price'] for r in qset]
```

but let's say I want to get the price every last X hours.

```
def _get_prices_per_time_slice(self, last_hours=24, time_slice_in_hours=4):
```

so if the current time is midnight (and zero seconds and minutes), I would want to get the prices for midnight, 8 pm, 4 pm, noon, 8 am and 4 am.  How do I add a filter to screen for prices every X hours?

Comment: What about `filter(created__in=list_of_desired_times)` ?

Comment: Why is `created__minute=end_time.minute` in there?

Comment: Are you looking for a single price for each of midnight, 8pm, 4pm etc; or **all** the prices stored in the given window:` [ [_all prices between 8pm and midnight_], [_all prices between 4pm and 8pm_], ...]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The range function in python helps to specify the incremental step value

SYNTAX : `range(start, stop, step)`

```
x = range(3, 20, 4)

for n in x:
  print(n)
#Gives output 
>>> 3
>>> 7
>>> 11
>>> 15
>>> 19
```

Just rewrite `created_range` to add the step value `time_slice_in_hours`

```
   created__range=[start_time, end_time, time_slice_in_hours]
```

**OPTION 1**

```
def _get_prices_per_time_slice(self, last_hours= 24,time_slice_in_hours=4):
    now = timezone.now()
    end_time = now.replace(second = 0, microsecond = 0)
    start_time = end_time - timedelta(hours=last_hours)
    qset = Price.objects.filter(
        created__range=[start_time, end_time, time_slice_in_hours],
        created__minute=end_time.minute
    ).values('price')
    return [r['price'] for r in qset]
```

However the syntax in [django query set api official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range)  fails to mention step parameter in `__range()` function i.e., it might not be supported by `created__range`.

**OPTION 2**

In that case you can use the below function where you can calculate time range `x_time_slice_list` using Python’s `DateTimeRange` function([official documentation](https://pypi.org/project/DateTimeRange/#examples)) and evaluate to `created__in`

```
from datetimerange import DateTimeRange
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def _get_prices_per_time_slice(self, last_hours= 24,time_slice_in_hours=4):
    now = timezone.now()
    end_time = now.replace(second = 0, microsecond = 0)
    start_time = end_time - timedelta(hours=last_hours)
    x_time_slice_list= []

    time_range = DateTimeRange(start_time, end_time)
    for value in time_range.range(relativedelta(hours=+time_slice_in_hours)):
           x_time_slice_list.append(value)

    qset = Price.objects.filter(
        created__in= x_time_slice_list,
        created__minute=end_time.minute
    ).values('price')
    return [r['price'] for r in qset]
```

Comment: Option 1 gives errors but option 2 seems to work.

Answer (score -1):

You could achieve this by handling the time slice filtering in python.

What I mean is if you take the function you have. i.e.

```py
def _get_prices_per_time_slice(self, last_hours=24):
    now = timezone.now()
    end_time = now.replace(second = 0, microsecond = 0)
    start_time = end_time - timedelta(hours=last_hours)
    qset = Price.objects.filter(
        created__range=[start_time, end_time],
        created__minute=end_time.minute
    ).values('price')
    return [r['price'] for r in qset]
```

And rewrite it as follows you to return the created data and handle the filtering in the return list comprehension.

```py
def _get_prices_per_time_slice(self, last_hours=24, time_slice_in_hours=4):
    now = timezone.now()
    end_time = now.replace(second = 0, microsecond = 0)
    start_time = end_time - timedelta(hours=last_hours)
    qset = Price.objects.filter(
        created__range=[start_time, end_time],
        created__minute=end_time.minute
    ).values('price', 'created')
    return [r.get('price') for r in qset if r.get('created').hour % time_slice_in_hours == 0]
```